# Ternary Operators in C

Tags: c, operators, ternary

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    short int i = 2;
    float f = 3;
    if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float)) 
        printf("float\n");
    else if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))
        printf("short int\n");
}
```

Output is "float". So i don't understand why `sizeof((x==2)?f:i)` always return `4`. 
I think declaration is missing variable at `(x==2)?f:i;` But it always returns `4(sizeof(f))`.

Can you help me! This is the first programming language I learn. I know this question very stupid but with me very hard. Thanks for spends your time:) Have a good day ;)

And the first time I try to use Stackoverflow, maybe have some mistakes. Hope you forgive me

Comment: The expression `a ? b : c` has **one** definite type that does not depend on `a`: it depends only on `b` and `c` and, that **one** type, is determined at compilation time. `0 ? 42 : 3.14` has type `double` and value `3.14`, `1 ? 42 : 3.14` has type `double` and value `42.0`

Comment: This is all clear, but I still wonder, what the OP _wants_ to achieve... I briefly thought I knew it, but..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question is if the expression not depend on a, so how do you know the expression depends on b or c?

Comment: @HoangLam not only "b or c" but "b and c". It follows the implicit conversion rules and has the same type as for example `b + c`

Answer (score 7):

A type of expression is deduced statically, at compile time.

So the type and size of `(x == 2) ? f : i` expression is known at compile time and will not change at runtime no matter what variable values are.

The type of result of ternary operator in this case is determined using usual arithmetic conversions ([C99 6.5.15p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.15p5) and [C99 6.3.1.8p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.8)). The type of `(x == 2) ? f : i` is determined as `float`.

The whole `sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i)` is evaluated at compile time and is equal to `sizeof(float)`.

You could move `x == 2` out of `sizeof` so that it is evaluated at runtime:

```
if ((x == 2 ? sizeof(f) : sizeof(i)) == sizeof(float))
```

Also note that it may happen that `sizeof(short int) == sizeof(float)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I finally understood the problem :)

Comment: Can you help me one more time :( when a ternary operator has Expression 1, not a logical expression.  I mean Expression 1 not return true or false. But variable always has a value from Expression 2 or Expression 3. Like `int y = 1, x = 0;` `int l = (y++, x++) ? y : x` => `l=1` and`int l = (y++, x++) ? x: y` =>`l=2` So,how i find out correct value of the variable

Comment: What is "Expression 1", 2, 3? To do `this`, remove the space after the \` backtick. ` space` and `space`. Well, in `(y++, x++) ? y : x` then `x` is incremented and returned, so it's 1, in `(y++, x++) ? x : y` then `y` is incremented and returned. I do not follow. Maybe `(y++, x++) ? y : x` is like to `y++; if (x) { x++; y; } else { x++; x; }`

Comment: **Variable = Expression 1 ? Expression 2 : Expression 3**

Comment: Any value different then 0 is true. A value equal to zero is false. `(y++, x++)` is 1, if value of `x` is different then 0. Maybe some links [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other) and [if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/if)

Comment: So sorry, the first time I try to use Stackoverflow. I will practice more

Comment: Yep, i understood, _Any value different then 0 is true. A value equal to zero is false_ it means `Expression1` maybe logic or not logic. If `Expression1` different then 0 is true, equal 0 is false, right?

Comment: Right. There is no such thing as "logic expression". The result of expression is literally compared with 0. For example [comparision operators like == or !=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison) just return an `int` with the value `0` or `1`.

Comment: thank you so much, C is the first language and there is so much to learn with me. Have a good day <3

Comment: _For example comparision operators like == or != just return an int with the value 0 or 1_ and Ternary Operator will return an `float` if values of `expression2` and `expression3` less than `float`-type  or `double` if more than. it's right? I realized through the examples:)

Comment: No or yes, depending on what "less then" means. The usual arithmetic conversions [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) and in [C99 6.3.1.8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.8). In `(x == 2) ? f : i` the variable `f` has type `float` and variable `i` has type `i`. Now on `f` and `i` the "usual arithmetic conversion" is performed, which say (from cppreference) `if one operand is float the other operand is implicitly converted as follows: integer type to float`. So `i` is converted to `float` and the result of `(x == 2) ? f : i` becomes `float`.

Comment: Och I guess what you mean by "less then" - the "conversion rank" from integer promotions. But conversion rank is only for integer types - floating point types do not have conversion rank. But kind-of yes, it works as-if `float` would have greater conversion rank then all integers.

Comment: last night i try with two `short int` , `(x == 2) ? f : i` mean `f` and `i` is `short int type`, so result always = 4  `float`. or Or maybe I misunderstood this problem :(

Comment: When both `f` and `i` are `short int`, then they while _usual arithmetic conversions_ they both first undergo implicit _integer promotions_, which converts them to both `int` type. [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) the `4) Otherwise, both operands are integers. Both operands undergo integer promotions` and below `Integer promotion is the implicit conversion of a value of any integer type with rank less or equal to rank of int .... to int or unsigned int`. So it becomes `sizeof(int)`. And most probably `sizeof(int)` = `sizeof(float)` on your platform.